# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EventBus') - pdfjs-dist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, pdfjs-dist, worker-loader

I am getting the above error if i use pdfjs-dist version ^3.0.279 or below version. and worker-loader with latest version 3.0.8 or 2.0.0
in code i am using like below.

```
import { PDFJS as PDFJSViewer } from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer.js';
// tried * as pdfjs from ... but din't help

let eventBus = new PDFJSViewer.EventBus();

this._pdfViewer = new PDFJSViewer.PDFViewer({
      container: viewerContainer,
      eventBus: this._eventBus,
    });
```

Please help to solve this issue